# ‘Nice-ness’ of a process inside a container

Tags: docker, nice, renice

So in my current app setting a certain process running inside a container runs another process. I need to set the nice value of the new process to be higher.

When ran on the OS I could just do
`nice -n19 second_task`. How does this work in the context of the docker container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When ran on the OS I could just do nice -n19 second_task. How does this work in the context of the docker container?

It works exactly the same way. When you're inside docker OS, you can just `nice -n19 second_task`.

Exactly the same restrictions apply as outside docker OS, so `nice` executable has to exists inside docker OS to be run, the same way the `nice` executable has to exist for you to run `nice` on your host OS. And user has to have appropriate limits (see `man limits.conf`) or be root.

Answer (score 1):

First of all one container should run only one process that is its single responsibility, containers should not be treated like VMs but like boundaries (container:)) for your services.

`nice` should work the same as it is working on the host because container processes are eventually processes on the host, so you could do `nice` in your Dockerfile CMD parameter. But this is something that you should control with a container orchestrator that is kubernetes for today de facto (there are other ones like docker swarm and nomad)